# return nvme list as array using jq and loop thru it

Tags: arrays, bash, jq

This is how I am grabbing all the NVME volumes:

```
all_nvme_volumes=$(sudo nvme list -o json | jq .Devices[].DevicePath)
```

This how the output looks like:

```
"/dev/nvme0n1" "/dev/nvme1n1" "/dev/nvme2n1" "/dev/nvme3n1" "/dev/nvme4n1" "/dev/nvme6n1"
```

How do I loop thru them process them individually?

I tried `for r in "${all_nvme_volumes[@]}"; do echo "Device Name: $r"; done` but the output is `Device Name: "/dev/nvme0n1" "/dev/nvme1n1" "/dev/nvme2n1" "/dev/nvme3n1" "/dev/nvme4n1" "/dev/nvme6n1"`
which is one string instead of each element of array:

Comment: Use with `jq` the `--raw-output` (or `-r`) option. It prints raw strings instead of JSON strings (being quoted) with a newline at the end of each item. Then you can use your intended `for` loop directly. No need to use Bash arrays. Also: Isn't `nvme` capable of providing a raw (non-JSON) output by itself, which would make it even easier to iterate over in the shell?

Comment: Please show output of `sudo nvme list -o json` and add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 3):

Populating a bash array with `mapfile` from null delimited raw output from `jq`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mapfile -d '' all_nvme_volumes < <(
  sudo nvme list --output-format=json |
  jq --join-output '.Devices[].DevicePath + "\u0000"'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution for bash < 4.4:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\t' read -r -a all_nvme_volumes < <(
    sudo nvme list -o json | jq -r '[ .Devices[].DevicePath ] | @tsv'
)
```

**note:** device paths shouldn't be escaped by `@tsv`, so you won't need to unescape the values, but in case you use this trick for other purposes, you can unescape a value with `printf -v value '%b' "$value"`

---

> How do I loop thru them process them individually?

Well, once you have the array, you can loop though its elements with:

```sh
for nvme_volume in "${all_nvme_volumes[@]}"
do
    # process "$nvme_volume"
done
```

But, if you only need to loop though the nvme volumes without storing them then you can use @LéaGris [null delimiter method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70220610/3387716) with a `while` loop:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r -d '' nvme_volume
do
    # process "$nvme_volume"
done < <(sudo nvme list -o json | jq -j '.Devices[].DevicePath + "\u0000"')
```